# What is Supervision (tortoise SVN) use? how to use SVN commands?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am very new with Supervision SVN.

I want to know about SVN command line with Tortoise And for what it exactly use.

Your answer will be very helpful to me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tortoise as well as Supervision (which I've never used) are just GUI front ends for [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) (a highly adopted version control software). 
[Here](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~vailen/svn_howto.htm) is a tutorial that might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Try having a little read through the [Red book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).

It is a good introduction to SVN.